# Django save form with User foreign key

Tags: django, django-forms

I am probably burt out because I don't see the problem here, and I'm sure it's something trivial.

I have a model form who's model is Profile (Profile is user through many forms on the site, works normally). In this particular form, I'm using only one field. When I try saving it, it breaks: null value in column "user_id" violates not-null constraint. User is a foreign key on the Profile model.

I have similar forms/views which only deal in one field from the Profile model and saving works okay on them. I'm comparing code and I simply can't see the difference. As I said, I'm probably burned out a bit.

This is my form:

```
class CompleteRegistration(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ('resume',)
```

This is the view:

```
def complete_registration(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = CompleteRegistration(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect(request.GET.get('next', ''))
    else:
        form = CompleteRegistration()

    context = {
        'form': form
    }

    return render_to_response('accounts/complete_registration.html', context, RequestContext(request))
```

It should be very simple, but I'm obviously missing something. The Profile model also has a uuid field. It exists in the failing row, which makes me even more puzzled. Why is there a uuid and no user? Any ideas? Could it be because the User instance in the view is actually a SimpleLazyObject?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Profile` instance is missing from the form. You should pass it as the `instance` parameter, otherwise the form tries to create a new instance (which doesn't have a `user_id`).

Comment: You mean in the else branch, like this? `form = CompleteRegistration(instance=request.user.get_profile())` - because that doesn't work, either; I get the same problem.

Comment: In both the `if request.method == 'POST':` and the `else:` branch.

Comment: I added this in the if branch: `form = CompleteRegistration(request.POST, instance=request.user.get_profile())` - it doesn't break anymore, it goes okay. However, the resume (FieldFile) is not saved. Is that a different problem altogether or is it related with this? Thanks.

Comment: That's probably another problem: see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/forms/api/#binding-uploaded-files.

Comment: Yes, it's okay now. I've added the enctype to the html form and the request.FILES along with request.POST when constructing the form in post.